# Verificação de arquivo no Servidor web

Tags: java, android, web-service, servidor

Seguinte, tenho um app Android, este aplicativo quer verificar a existência de uma imagem na web para poder carregar pelo Picasso, caso a imagem não exista num endereço www.algumacoisa.com/img/imagem5.png vou mostrar uma mensagem.
Então o que preciso é validar a imagem antes de carregar, ou tentar carregar e se não existe me informar para que eu posso definir uma mensagem.
Acho que está bem explicado.
Código:
//Aqui quero a verificação se existe um arquivo nesse endereço: //www.lojaimpacto.com.br/img/foto05.png

if(arquivo existe){

```
        iv_xml01_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_xml01_logo);
        Picasso.with(lista_fones.this)
                .load(www.lojaimpacto.com.br/img/foto05.png)
                .resize(300, 155)
                .centerInside()
                .into(iv_xml01_logo);
```

} else {

```
 System.out.println("Arquivo não existe");
```

}

Comment: Você pode editar sua resposta e colocar o código que está usando no servidor e também dizer em que local está a imagem?

Answer (score 1):

Método `exists()`.

[Exemplo:](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java/)

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileChecker
{    public static void main(String args[])
     {    File f = new File("caminho_para o arquivo");
          if(f.exists())
          {    System.out.println("Arquivo existe");
          }else
          {    System.out.println("Não encontrei, procuro novamente?");
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado. Mas este método não está fazendo a verificação no servidor. O que devo fazer?

Comment: Como assim ? Coloca o código que está a tentar ...

Comment: Acho que ele se refere ao rootpath da app

Comment: Bom vamos ver... Já tem uma galera olhando agora só depende dele...

Comment: File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "http://lojaimpacto.com.br/guia/img/empresas/logo/img_508.png");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Existe");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Não existe");
        }

Comment: File file = new File("http://lojaimpacto.com.br/guia/img/empresas/logo/img_508.png");
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Existe");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Não existe");
        }

Comment: Todo jeito da como que Não existe

Comment: Tenho que fazer a verificação pois a imagem pode estar ou como PNG ou JPG. E para chamar o picasso tenho que indicar qual a extensão.